# Not getting token for Push notification on iOS 11.4.1

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have integrated Push notification, I am able to get Push notification token on iOS 11.2, iOS 11.3, etc version. But not able to receive device token on iOS 11.4.1 version.

The method `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` and `didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError` not getting called.

Any one is facing this issue? I want to check is this device issue or iOS version issue?

Comment: Have you requested permissions from the user? Do you have the correct entitlements setup? Is the App authorised (by the user)?

Comment: Yes, User is authorised by using API: UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                print("granted: (\(granted)")
                
            };

Answer (score 0):

Can you please requested permissions as condinally in `Appdelegate`  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
 if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) {(accepted, error) in
            if !accepted {
                print("Notification access denied.")
            }
        }
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Then please try retrieve token with

```
 extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

        func application(_ application: UIApplication, 
       didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
               let token = deviceToken.map { String(format: "%02.2hhx", $0) }.joined()
               print(token)

     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the same Implementation is done in my code. And also I am getting Push notification token for iOS 11.3 version also. I want to know for iOS 11.4.1.